# How to animate changes in UIButton content alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Several of UIButton's properties are not inherently animatable. One of these properties is the `contentHorizontalAlignment` property. After searching SO with no luck, I came up with the answer below to solve the "not-animatable" issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method first animates `UIButton`'s `titleLabel` frame manually, then sets the content alignment and content edge insets to preserve `UIButton` default behavior.

```
CGRect frame = button.titleLabel.frame;
frame.origin.x = 10;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    button.titleLabel.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

You should animate `layoutIfNeeded` after change alignment value:

**Objective C:**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{       
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

**Swift3:**

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```